# PHP, MySQL - Simple search with unwanted result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic search option on my local site which uses unique 8 digit user number for each user in the MySQL and it works (eg: if the user number is matched to user it will display all of the records associated with that user number) its just I get unwanted result when the search is concluded, and the unwanted result is that if for example I do a search for a user with the following no 12345678 and user exits it will show the result but lets say I do a search for 12345677 and user does not exist I will get the message User fount but no data displayed.

Search form code:

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="query" placeholder="Student Number" autofocus/>
   <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

search.php

```
include_once("config.php");
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loan WHERE userno=$query");
 if(empty($result)) {

 //  } else{

echo "<center><table border='0' id='3'>";
echo "<tr id='2'>";
echo "<td><center>System Message</center></td></tr>";
echo "<tr id='loan4'><br />";
echo "<td><center><h1>No Record Found</h1>";
echo "<br/><a href='index.php' class='button button1 link'>Go back</a>";
echo "<br/>OR</a>";
echo "<br/><a href='add_new_loan.php' class='button button1 link'>Add New Loan</a>";
echo "</center></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table></center>";}

  else{  
?>
    <table width='95%' border='0' id='loan1'>

    <tr id='loan2'>
        <td width="120">User No.</td>
        <td width="130">Full Name</td>
        <td width="90">Amount</td>
        <td width="100">aken</td>
        <td width="100">Due</td>
        <td width="248">Notes</td>
        <td width="120" align="center">Options</td>

    </tr>


    <?php 

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  

        echo "<tr id='4'>";
        echo "<td>".$res['userno']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"receipt.php?id=$res[id]\" target=\"_blank\">".$res['name']."&nbsp;".$res['surname']."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['loana']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['datet']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['dated']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['notes']."</td>";  
        echo "</tr>";   
    }

     echo "<center><table border='0' id='loan3'>";
echo "<tr id='loan2'>";
echo "<td><center>System Message</center></td></tr>";
echo "<tr id='4'><br />";
echo "<td><center><h1>Record Found</h1>";
echo "<br/><a href='index.php' class='button button1 link'>Go back</a>";
```

Also I have tried `!empty` but no joy, Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. stop using `deprecated+removed mysql_* library`. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead of it.2. you have to use `num_rows()` of `mysql_*` to check that data coming or not.3. use `prepared statements` to prevent from `SQL INJECTION`(new libraries have those)

Comment: `Accounting` + `mysql_*` + `SQL Injection` = Problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your current code by using `mysql_num_rows()` like below:-

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");
$query = $_GET['query']; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM loan WHERE userno=$query");
 if(mysql_num_rows($result) >0) {
?>
    <table width='95%' border='0' id='loan1'>

    <tr id='loan2'>
        <td width="120">User No.</td>
        <td width="130">Full Name</td>
        <td width="90">Amount</td>
        <td width="100">aken</td>
        <td width="100">Due</td>
        <td width="248">Notes</td>
        <td width="120" align="center">Options</td>

    </tr>


    <?php 

    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  

        echo "<tr id='4'>";
        echo "<td>".$res['userno']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"receipt.php?id=$res[id]\" target=\"_blank\">".$res['name']."&nbsp;".$res['surname']."</a></td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['loana']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['datet']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['dated']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['notes']."</td>";  
        echo "</tr>";   
    }
}else{
        echo "<center><table border='0' id='3'>";
        echo "<tr id='2'>";
        echo "<td><center>System Message</center></td></tr>";
        echo "<tr id='loan4'><br />";
        echo "<td><center><h1>No Record Found</h1>";
        echo "<br/><a href='index.php' class='button button1 link'>Go back</a>";
        echo "<br/>OR</a>";
        echo "<br/><a href='add_new_loan.php' class='button button1 link'>Add New Loan</a>";
        echo "</center></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table></center>";
}?>
```

Note:-

Stop using `deprecated+removed mysql_* library`. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` along with `prepared statements` to prevent from `SQL INJECTION`.

REFREENCE:-

[mysqli_* with prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO with prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1):

The $result might be not completely empty.

Try to use mysql_num_rows().

Example:

```
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==0) { 
       //PERFORM ACTION
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to stop using the `mysql_*` functions, they are depreciated and completely removed as of PHP 7 user `mysqli_*` or PDO with prepared statements.

See the links below :

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Then make use of prepared statements to prevent sql injections.

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Follow the link above to use prepared statements.

this is how your code should look :

**config.php**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
?>
```

**search.php**

```
<?php


include_once("config.php");
$query = $_GET['query']; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM loan WHERE userno= $query "; // use prepared statements from the link I provided above

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //Records found print the table
    //OUTPUT THE TABLE AND HEADINGS HERE BEFORE THE LOOP
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //fetch and output each data of row to your table td's

    }


}else{

//user data not found print message

}
```